# PayPal API for funding business account

Tags: paypal

All the users on my site have a personal account. I would like to add paypal as a payment method to fund a user account. Upon a fund the user account will be credited so he will be able to pay for the services I provide. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible you can write a script that after the users payment several lines of code get executed that activates your service and credits your account.

The easiest way of doing this is by using a payment provider that sits between paypal and your site. They can deliver you directly the scripts and API you need.

Ofcourse you can also make them yourself. Not sure if the PayPal API already includes this functionality.

I hope that this is of any help

Answer (score 0):

Paypal provides an API to integrate and customize its payment platform to your website.

For starters this limk will give you a breakdown on what you can do with the api.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/

try this link if you are keen on developing that part of your site.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/